# how to give diffrent multiple url hyperlink for single facebook message post

Tags: android, facebook, url, post, hyperlink

I am sending message to facebook wall my post contain an image and title and caption and description.I want to give different hyperlink for different item of my single post.I am successful in sending post on facebook wall.but not able to give multiple url hyperlink.My code is here

```
 Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
        postParams.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken());
        postParams.putString("name", "LangGuage");
        postParams.putString("href", "http://www.facebook.com");
        postParams.putString("caption",msg);
        postParams.putString("picture",url1);
        postParams.putString("description","Powered by::Hunka Technology Pvt. Ltd.");

        postParams.putString("link", "http://www.hunkatech.com");
```

My image and message and title all have the same link.how to give different url to all.

UPDATE: I also tried to do this but get this:{"error":{"message":"(#100) Missing message or attachment","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}

```
 JSONObject attachment = new JSONObject();

            attachment.put(Facebook.TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken());
            attachment.put("message", "hi ");
            attachment.put("name", "LangGuage");
            attachment.put("link", "http://www.facebook.com");
            attachment.put("caption", msg);


            JSONObject media = new JSONObject();
            media.put("type", "image");
            media.put("picture", url1);
            media.put("link","http://www.google.com");
            attachment.put("media", new JSONArray().put(media));



            JSONObject properties = new JSONObject();

            JSONObject prop1 = new JSONObject();


            prop1.put("text", "Powered by::Hunka Technology Pvt. Ltd.");
            prop1.put("link", "http://www.hunkatech.com");
            properties.put("Get the App for free", prop1);


            attachment.put("properties", properties);

            Log.d("FACEBOOK", attachment.toString());

            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("attachment", attachment.toString());

            String res = facebook.request("me/feed", params, "POST");
            System.out.println("----resp" + res);
```

Is it possible from any way..

Answer (score 1):

First, the `href` field doesn't exist for a `post`, but this will simply be ignored.

You can't get what you want. A post can contain:

- a message that allows as many links as you wish,
- **only one** caption link (a caption has a title, description, image and url).

This sample code:

```
Bundle postParams = new Bundle();

postParams.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken());

/* Caption information (to highlight one link only) */
postParams.putString("caption", "Stack Overflow");
postParams.putString("picture", "http://myrrix.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/stackoverflow.png");
postParams.putString("description","A language-independent collaboratively edited question and answer site for programmers.");
postParams.putString("name", "stackoverflow.com"); //Name of the link
postParams.putString("link", "http://stackoverflow.com");
/* End of the caption information */

response = facebook.request("me/feed", postParams, "POST");
```

... results to:

[image: A post link with several links]

The division you can see on the image above is in fact **one link**, a link which is specified by the `link` field. All the other fields only are textual and pictural information. In HTML it would be:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com"><div id="caption"> ... </div></a>
```

Comment: item means i consider Title,discription and image as different items of one post.I want when i click on image i want to open google.com and when i click on title i want to open facebook.com and on click discription it should open another site.how it can be done i dont need message.

Comment: Thanks for support but i dont get ur point.is this possible if i click on ur stack-overflow icon it will contain different link and if i click of text if will contain different link.because it is possible in iphone.if yes,then how.can u give me sample code

Comment: My post just explained that you **can't** do this.